Same webpage on 2 sites (multisite)
Is it possible to display the same page (e.g."About me") shared by 2 sites on a Wordpress multisite?
TIA
Charles

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@Community Seems answerable to me? Both the old and new versions of the question.

I suspect the answer is no, not without jumping through a few hoops, because the posts for different sites are stored in different post tables. But I'll let someone who knows post a definitive answer.

Some possible work-arounds: a special post type or block that reads content from another site, either direct from the database or over REST, or from a shared space (e.g. site options); a mechanism that automatically syncs the about page on one site to the other site, and either syncs edits on the second site back again or prevents edits on the second site.
